# Google Spreadsheets Add old number with new number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add a number to an old number. For example A1 contains "5", and I write "10" into B1, then A1 should show "15".

When I type "10" in B1 again, then A1 should show "25", so A1 adds the previous number with the new number.

I dont want to do mental arithemtic every time.
Is this possible with Google Sheets?

Comment: curious why you want to over write A1? It will create a circular reference which is not allowed.. the value has to be sored somewhere for it know.. so if you over write it.. what happens to the old one? Why not simply do the addition in c? C1=A1+B1 
why make this so complicated?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether the use of Google Apps Script is includedin your goal, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that in your situation when Google Apps Script is used, your goal might be able to be achieved. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and save the script.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getA1Notation() != "B1") return;
  const [a, b] = range.offset(0, -1, 1, 2).getValues()[0];
  range.offset(0, -1).setValue(a + b);
}
```

#### Testing:

When you use this script, please put a number to the cell "B1". By this, the script is automatically run by firing the OnEdit trigger as follows. So when you directly run the script with the script editor, an error occurs because the event object is not declared. Please be careful this.

[image]

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script from your question. So when your actual situation is different from your question, please modify the above script.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: If you want to do that in other cells, for example instead A1 -> I10 and for B1 -> J10, you have to change the variable, but then it doesnt work anymore, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @renb Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, about your new question of `If you want to do that in other cells, for example instead A1 -> I10 and for B1 -> J10, you have to change the variable, but then it doesnt work anymore, what am I doing wrong?`, I cannot understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question.

Comment: I am trying to add a number to an old number. For example I10 contains "5", and I write "10" into J10, then I10 should show "15". 

When I type "10" into J10 again, I10 should show "25"

Comment: @renb Thank you for replying. In your new question, you want to use the cells "I10" and "J10" instead of the cells "A1" and "B1". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: @renb Thank you for replying. In that case, please modify `if (range.getA1Notation() != "B1") return;` to `if (range.getA1Notation() != "J10") return;` and test it again. When I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: So thats the changed code now. when I run the code with numbers in J10, this error message appears ![Valid XHTML](http://prntscr.com/24onaqp)

`function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getA1Notation() != "J10") return;
  const [a, b] = range.offset(0, -1, 1, 2).getValues()[0];
  range.offset(0, -1).setValue(a + b);
}`

I am sorry for my bad formatting, I am new to stackoverflow and for my unaccurate english, its not my mother tongue either :D

Comment: @renb Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `when I run the code with numbers in J10` and your error, about your new issue, I'm worried that you might directly run your script. In that case, such error occurs. In my answer, OnEdit trigger is used. The script is automatically run with the OnEdit trigger. So in order to run the script, please put a number to the cell "J10". By this, the script is automatically run. I deeply apologize that I used OnEdit trigger for achieving your new question.

Comment: Oh it works, I did something wrong :D. Thank you very much!!!!